# Layout crashes application with ANR in certain devices

Tags: android, android-layout, crash

I've struggling with this problem for days. Our app works in several devices but in some it crashes when certain layouts are loaded (ANR crash). Below one example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/view_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/back_searchbar"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/filterEdit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/search"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/searchBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_magnify" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        style="@style/mmListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/view_background"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="8dp"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

For instance the app crashes in Galaxy S running Android 2.3.3 (ANR Crash). We know other models which have the same problem. What intrigues us is that if we remove the FrameLayout part from the layout, it is loaded correctly. Also, the same app runs in other devices without any problem.

We use BugSense but such crashes do not result in reports.

Here is the last lines from logcat:

```
07-16 14:34:16.113: D/dalvikvm(17786): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 415K, 43% free 5210K/9095K, external 5930K/6095K, paused 39ms
07-16 14:34:20.312: I/dalvikvm(17786): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
07-16 14:34:21.316: W/dalvikvm(17786): threadid=4: spin on suspend #1 threadid=37 (pcf=0)
07-16 14:34:22.066: W/dalvikvm(17786): threadid=4: spin on suspend #2 threadid=37 (pcf=0)
07-16 14:34:22.066: I/dalvikvm(17786): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
07-16 14:34:22.066: I/dalvikvm(17786):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4050fbd8 self=0x114e90
07-16 14:34:22.066: I/dalvikvm(17786):   | sysTid=17789 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1134160
07-16 14:34:22.066: I/dalvikvm(17786):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
07-16 14:34:22.066: I/dalvikvm(17786): "(null)" prio=0 tid=37 RUNNABLE
07-16 14:34:22.066: I/dalvikvm(17786):   | group="(null; initializing?)" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x408192d8 self=0x3c9708
07-16 14:34:22.066: I/dalvikvm(17786):   | sysTid=17933 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3954088
07-16 14:34:22.066: I/dalvikvm(17786):   at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:~386)
07-16 14:34:22.066: I/dalvikvm(17786):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
07-16 14:34:22.816: W/dalvikvm(17786): threadid=4: spin on suspend #3 threadid=37 (pcf=0)
07-16 14:34:22.816: I/dalvikvm(17786): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
07-16 14:34:22.816: I/dalvikvm(17786):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4050fbd8 self=0x114e90
07-16 14:34:22.816: I/dalvikvm(17786):   | sysTid=17789 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1134160
07-16 14:34:22.816: I/dalvikvm(17786):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
07-16 14:34:22.816: I/dalvikvm(17786): "(null)" prio=0 tid=37 RUNNABLE
07-16 14:34:22.816: I/dalvikvm(17786):   | group="(null; initializing?)" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x408192d8 self=0x3c9708
07-16 14:34:22.816: I/dalvikvm(17786):   | sysTid=17933 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3954088
07-16 14:34:23.019: I/dalvikvm(17786):   at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:~386)
07-16 14:34:23.019: I/dalvikvm(17786):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
07-16 14:34:23.769: W/dalvikvm(17786): threadid=4: spin on suspend #4 threadid=37 (pcf=0)
07-16 14:34:23.769: I/dalvikvm(17786): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
07-16 14:34:23.769: I/dalvikvm(17786):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4050fbd8 self=0x114e90
07-16 14:34:23.769: I/dalvikvm(17786):   | sysTid=17789 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1134160
07-16 14:34:23.769: I/dalvikvm(17786):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
07-16 14:34:23.769: I/dalvikvm(17786): "(null)" prio=0 tid=37 RUNNABLE
07-16 14:34:23.769: I/dalvikvm(17786):   | group="(null; initializing?)" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x408192d8 self=0x3c9708
07-16 14:34:23.769: I/dalvikvm(17786):   | sysTid=17933 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3954088
07-16 14:34:23.851: I/dalvikvm(17786):   at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:~386)
07-16 14:34:23.851: I/dalvikvm(17786):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
07-16 14:34:24.601: W/dalvikvm(17786): threadid=4: spin on suspend #5 threadid=37 (pcf=0)
07-16 14:34:24.601: I/dalvikvm(17786): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
07-16 14:34:24.601: I/dalvikvm(17786):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4050fbd8 self=0x114e90
07-16 14:34:24.601: I/dalvikvm(17786):   | sysTid=17789 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1134160
07-16 14:34:24.601: I/dalvikvm(17786):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
07-16 14:34:24.601: I/dalvikvm(17786): "(null)" prio=0 tid=37 RUNNABLE
07-16 14:34:24.601: I/dalvikvm(17786):   | group="(null; initializing?)" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x408192d8 self=0x3c9708
07-16 14:34:24.601: I/dalvikvm(17786):   | sysTid=17933 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3954088
07-16 14:34:24.601: I/dalvikvm(17786):   at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:~386)
07-16 14:34:24.601: I/dalvikvm(17786):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
07-16 14:34:25.351: W/dalvikvm(17786): threadid=4: spin on suspend #6 threadid=37 (pcf=0)
07-16 14:34:25.351: I/dalvikvm(17786): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
07-16 14:34:25.351: I/dalvikvm(17786):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4050fbd8 self=0x114e90
07-16 14:34:25.351: I/dalvikvm(17786):   | sysTid=17789 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1134160
07-16 14:34:25.355: I/dalvikvm(17786):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
07-16 14:34:25.355: I/dalvikvm(17786): "(null)" prio=0 tid=37 RUNNABLE
07-16 14:34:25.355: I/dalvikvm(17786):   | group="(null; initializing?)" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x408192d8 self=0x3c9708
07-16 14:34:25.355: I/dalvikvm(17786):   | sysTid=17933 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3954088
07-16 14:34:25.359: I/dalvikvm(17786):   at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:~386)
07-16 14:34:25.359: I/dalvikvm(17786):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Any idea about what is going on? Or how can we avoid such problem?

Comment: Please post the log with errors.

Comment: What does our friend logcat say

Comment: @Slartibartfast I think it says not much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. "@drawable/back_searchbar" uses a JPG image (gradient background). We don't know the reason but replacing the image by a shape filled with a gradient solved the problem on those models that the app crashed consistently.